# Delete all objects in schema using batch file in Oracle

Tags: oracle, batch-file, database-schema, sql-drop

I have below Select query which will generate delete statements to delete all objects in schema.

```
select 'DROP '||OBJECT_TYPE||' '||OWNER||'.'||OBJECT_NAME
       || case when OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE'
               then ' CASCADE CONSTRAINTS PURGE' else '' end
       ||';' 
  from all_objects
 where OWNER = 'RATOR_MONITORING';
```

I want to create batch file and suppose that instead of generating delete statements separetly I can create may be cursor or something and save it in batch file and run the batch file to delete all contents in schema. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find many script in the Internet. Neither of them work on 100%. There can we various gotchas. Like scheduler chains or materialized view groups.

This is the one I use (it is also inspired by one I found in the Internet)

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited
declare
  v_ItemCount integer;
begin
  SELECT count(*)
    INTO v_ItemCount
    FROM ALL_OBJECTS AO
   WHERE AO.OWNER = '&USER'
     AND AO.OBJECT_TYPE NOT IN ('INDEX', 'LOB')
     AND AO.OBJECT_NAME NOT LIKE 'BIN$%';
  while (v_ItemCount > 0) loop
    for v_Cmd in (SELECT 'drop ' || AO.OBJECT_TYPE || ' ' || '"'||AO.OWNER||'"'|| '.' || '"'||AO.OBJECT_NAME||'"' ||
                         DECODE(AO.OBJECT_TYPE,
                                'TABLE',
                                ' CASCADE CONSTRAINTS',
                                '') as DROPCMD,
                                AO.OWNER,
                                AO.OBJECT_TYPE,
                                AO.OBJECT_NAME
                    FROM ALL_OBJECTS AO
                   WHERE AO.OWNER = '&USER'
                     AND AO.OBJECT_TYPE NOT IN ('INDEX', 'LOB')
                     AND AO.OBJECT_NAME NOT LIKE 'BIN$%') 
    loop
      begin
        if v_Cmd.OBJECT_TYPE = 'SCHEDULE' then
          DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_SCHEDULE(v_Cmd.OWNER||'.'||v_Cmd.OBJECT_NAME, true);
        ELSIF v_Cmd.OBJECT_TYPE = 'JOB' then
          DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_JOB(v_Cmd.OWNER||'.'||v_Cmd.OBJECT_NAME, true);
        ELSIF v_Cmd.OBJECT_TYPE = 'PROGRAM' then
          DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_PROGRAM(v_Cmd.OWNER||'.'||v_Cmd.OBJECT_NAME, true);                              
        else
          execute immediate v_Cmd.dropcmd;
        end if;  
        dbms_output.put_line(v_Cmd.dropcmd);        
      exception
        when others then
          null; -- ignore errors
      end;
    end loop;
    SELECT count(*)
      INTO v_ItemCount
      FROM ALL_OBJECTS AO
     WHERE AO.OWNER = '&USER'     
       AND AO.OBJECT_TYPE NOT IN ('INDEX','LOB')
       AND AO.OBJECT_NAME NOT LIKE 'BIN$%';
  end loop;
  execute immediate 'purge dba_recyclebin';
end;
```

Comment: it works for me but what if dont want to delete scheduler job then how to change the code ?

Comment: And i dont want to provide input values. It should directly run

Comment: I usually connect to the database as sys (sysdba user) and I do not want to drop any internal database objects. if you want to clear your own schema when replace every occurrence of `ALL_` with `USER_`. Then remover `..OWNER = '&USER' ` from all where clauses.

Comment: You can also extend the list of of ignored object types `OBJECT_TYPE NOT IN ('INDEX', 'LOB')` if you want to exclude something.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the script

```
begin
  for i in (select * from dba_objects where owner = 'SO' and object_type <> 'TABLE')
  loop
    execute immediate 'drop ' || i.object_type || ' ' || i.object_name;
  end loop;
  for j in (select * from dba_objects where owner = 'SO' and object_type = 'TABLE')
  loop
    execute immediate 'drop ' || j.object_type || ' ' || j.object_name || ' cascade constraints';
  end loop;
end;
/
```

This link provides details about how to create shell script or batch script to run sql scripts.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-shell-scripting

Comment: this script gives me an error as cannot delete index used for enforcement of keys

Answer (score 1):

```
Here we go i have compiled a shell to perform the Purge Schema. Let me know if this helps.

#weekly report
#!/bin/ksh
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/1020
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH:.
export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8

ABC=`sqlplus -s <username>/<password>@<sid> <<+
set sqlbl on;
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
  v_ItemCount INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO v_ItemCount
  FROM ALL_OBJECTS AO
  WHERE AO.OWNER          = '&USER'
  AND AO.OBJECT_TYPE NOT IN ('INDEX', 'LOB')
  AND AO.OBJECT_NAME NOT LIKE 'BIN$%';
  WHILE (v_ItemCount > 0)
  LOOP
    FOR v_Cmd IN
    (SELECT 'drop '
      || AO.OBJECT_TYPE
      || ' '
      || '"'
      ||AO.OWNER
      ||'"'
      || '.'
      || '"'
      ||AO.OBJECT_NAME
      ||'"'
      || DECODE(AO.OBJECT_TYPE, 'TABLE', ' CASCADE CONSTRAINTS', '') AS DROPCMD,
      AO.OWNER,
      AO.OBJECT_TYPE,
      AO.OBJECT_NAME
    FROM ALL_OBJECTS AO
    WHERE AO.OWNER          = '&USER'
    AND AO.OBJECT_TYPE NOT IN ('INDEX', 'LOB')
    AND AO.OBJECT_NAME NOT LIKE 'BIN$%'
    )
    LOOP
      BEGIN
        IF v_Cmd.OBJECT_TYPE = 'SCHEDULE' THEN
          DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_SCHEDULE(v_Cmd.OWNER||'.'||v_Cmd.OBJECT_NAME, true);
        ELSIF v_Cmd.OBJECT_TYPE = 'JOB' THEN
          DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_JOB(v_Cmd.OWNER||'.'||v_Cmd.OBJECT_NAME, true);
        ELSIF v_Cmd.OBJECT_TYPE = 'PROGRAM' THEN
          DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_PROGRAM(v_Cmd.OWNER||'.'||v_Cmd.OBJECT_NAME, true);
        ELSE
          EXECUTE immediate v_Cmd.dropcmd;
        END IF;
        dbms_output.put_line(v_Cmd.dropcmd);
      EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        NULL; -- ignore errors
      END;
    END LOOP;
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO v_ItemCount
    FROM ALL_OBJECTS AO
    WHERE AO.OWNER          = '&USER'
    AND AO.OBJECT_TYPE NOT IN ('INDEX','LOB')
    AND AO.OBJECT_NAME NOT LIKE 'BIN$%';
  END LOOP;
  EXECUTE immediate 'purge dba_recyclebin';
END;
/
exit
+`
```

Comment: this script is getting hanged and its very complicated too. Do we have any other much simpler script to delete all objects ?

Comment: Yes we have.. Let me prepare one for you a simpler approach :). I basically copied the script which worked for u as mentioned in below answer. I just refracted it inside a shell and tried in my workspace it works fine